# SDK GXP Legend OpenGeo Suite Scroll?

Tags: boundless-suite, legend, sdk

Is it possible to have the legend scroll using the OpenGeo Suite SDK and GXP. Following this tutorial [Tutorial Link](http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/doc/tutorial/viewer/legend.html)It is possible to have it any size if external as the height and width can be changed but when embedded into the west container, if too many layers are selected the legend doesn't fully display each layer?

Suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the ExtJS `autoScroll` option in the legend's `outputConfig`, e.g.:

```
{
    ptype: "gxp_legend",
    outputConfig: {
        autoScroll: true
    },
    outputTarget: "legend"
}
```